# Writing to NFC tag with android/flutter

Tags: android, flutter, nfc

I am trying to write to an NFC tag on a button click with flutter. I couldn't get a flutter library to work because every time I attempted to write to the tag the android "Tag Collected" popped up and wouldn't write to the tag.

So I am trying to use native android code to write to the NFC tag but all the tutorials I am find don't seem to offer much help. Does anyone know how I should go about this?
I've made a channel to that talks to android but I'm stuck.

Comment: Have you tried [nfc_in_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/nfc_in_flutter) Flutter plugin ?

Comment: That is what  i was using but every time I tried to write to it popped up the "Tag collected" android thing

Comment: Someone has reported this issue with a possible solution https://github.com/semlette/nfc_in_flutter/issues/51

Comment: Should i be attempting to read the tag first then writing to it?

Comment: It should not be necessary

Comment: Ok ive got it working some how by just copying and pasting the code again.